# AWS Api Gateway: Post Processing

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sns

is it possible to do a post processing (besides transformation) of response in API Gateway?
For instance POST call to API Gateway goes to my Rest API and after response is return, API Gateway publishes an event (call lambda or SNS in the background).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At present, there is no direct option for this in Api-Gateway. However, you can create a JSON message and push it to SNS topic which can call AWS Lambda or can be pushed into SQS for later process. Pushing into SNS can be done using AWS SDK.

Comment: Thanks. You mean to create Json message and push it to SNS from my code, not from api gateway, right?